# TinyMCE Image manager config issue [Image source]

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce

I have problem with tinyMCE image manager plugin.
My configuration details are :

```
<add key="filesystem.rootpath" 
     value="E:\ABC\My Project Name\CMSFolder\CMSImages\"/>
```

using thic config,tinyMCE works fine.i can upload images to above specified folder.also i can see images in editor also
This data also gets saved in DB successfulyy.
image tag is created in this way

```
<img src="CMSImages/error.png" width="375" height="300" />
```

The problem is that when i try to display this content in my asp.net literal or div control in FinancePage.aspx page,image is not displayed.
because it's src path is **[src="CMSImages/error.png"].**
It must be **[src="\CMSFolder\CMSImages\error.png"]**.then only it can display image.
my FinancePage.aspx page is in My Project Name folder.
any suggestion?
how to configure this?